# Specify MARS Input File

Tags: assembly, mips, spim, mars-simulator

I'm testing a MIPS Assembly program in MARS, and would like to specify a file to take as input during execution (sort of like what I can accomplish by redirecting stdin with the following UNIX command):

> spim -file [filename].s < [input_file]

Is there a way to accomplish something like this in MARS? This is a homework assignment and I'm limited to the standard MIPS syscalls, so I can't use MARS' extended file operations set.

I'm also open to other methods of doing this (in any MIPS simulator). I just need a way to step through the program and debug as it's running. The MIPS solution above just runs until it finishes or throws an exception, at which point I can't step back or examine memory contents.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/MarsHelpDebugging.html) for information on stepping through and debugging a MARS program.

Comment: I get how to do that. I'm trying to specify a file as input. For now, I've resorted to typing all the lines in manually, but I'd really love for that to be automated.